# What's the maximum player level?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

There is an achievement/trophy for getting to "the maximum player level" (unspecified in the text of said achievement/trophy).

In researching, I found the highest unlock comes at player level 53 (the joke weapons). Is that the highest player level? If not, what is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have all the unlockables at level 70, although the maximum level is 99.

Answer (score 3):

The highest player level achievable is actually **99**. As much of a pain as that is, I guess Namco/Bandai really really want you play this game to death.